# css box sizing override issue caused by bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this checkbox button where I am trying to keep the text in the center. The button works fine normally, but when I include bootstrap, the text goes top left corner.

I have searched similar issues and applied

```
.round-button *,
.round-button *:before,
.round-button *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box !important;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box !important;
    box-sizing: content-box !important;
}
```

But it doesn't work. Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wga27Lvy/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Position your label absolute and centre it that way using the translateY trick:

```
label {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-weight: 700;
    position: absolute !important;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 100%;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Then add position relative to your button:

```
.round-button{
    position:relative;
}
```

Working example
http://jsfiddle.net/4qqczsw0/3/

Comment: It becomes a square after checking. Also the text seem to inclined to right. Adding more buttons causes some weird issues too http://jsfiddle.net/4qqczsw0/3/

Comment: This will fix the square issue .round-button-circle {position:relative}

Comment: Text looks bang on central to me, there may be some padding on the button div somewhere that is throwing it off. Can you give an example of the weird issues?

Comment: nvm setting .round-button-circle {position:relative} fixes those issues too